# Working With Audio in PyProcessing

Tags: python, audio, pyprocessing

I am learning Pyprocessing.  It comes with the regular processing platform that originally was written in Java.  Many of the example projects that come bundled with processing have also been written in Python but not any of the audio libraries/examples.

I tried searching google but haven't found anything as of yet.

Does anyone know of a good resource where I can learn to do basic things with the audio library in pyprocessing such as playing audio and filtering audio?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) and [SWMixer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SWMixer) for basic audio needs on a [project](http://www.hirschandmann.com/portfolio/vigo/).

Other python-audio resources I found useful at the time:

- [Scott W Harden's blog post on FFT analysis in Python](http://www.swharden.com/blog/2013-05-09-realtime-fft-audio-visualization-with-python/) (lots of neat things there)
- [PyAudioMixer](https://github.com/nvahalik/PyAudioMixer/blob/master/README.md)
- [python-sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.0/)
  I hadn't used these exhaustively though to be able to advise on which one is most stable and easy to use.